# Java Swing Panel collapse into drop down on resize

Tags: java, swing, ribbon

I am working on ribbons using Java Swing technology. I am not using the already made framework called Flamingo (it's not giving the style I want), rather I am implementing it via the netbeans swing drag and drop. I want to make the panels collapse into drop down when the window is resized.

Like if we resized the window to be very small, we will have 3 dropdowns: File, Preferences and Help. Each drop down gives the elements in each section.

Any ideas how to achieve this?[image]

Comment: You mean you wanna make you panel look like [this](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/uploads/2017/10/bs4-dropdown-tips.png?width=600&key=c1a510621ad573821ec336b66b38216a4e588d01c1be8bda93dc683e42ed326f)? Why don't you add a horizontal scrolling option.

Comment: @Goion Yes like this. These are the requirements.

Comment: You can create two panes. One with the drop down and other with the ribbon menu. Using component listener you can determine if the window is being resized and when it does bring the pane with drop down menu to front.